# how can i use return@ with if expression in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

What should I use instead of the whats_there parameter so the value of x will be 0?

```
val x =
    if (true) {
        for (i in 1..5)
            if (i == 4)
                return@whats_there 0
        1
    }
    else 2
```

Comment: Some previously defined label https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels in your code snippet there are none.

In your case that `for` loop doesn't do anything so the whole block has no effect. That expression has value `5`. Since that's the last statement of the if

Answer (score 2):

```
val x = if (ok) run {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        if (i == someValue)
            return@run 10
    }
    5
} else 2
```

or

```
val x = if (ok) {
    if (someValue in 1..5) 10 else 5
} else 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a `return` like that is hard to read and prone to error.  This example is probably too simplified to show your real problem, but it looks like you could use [`any()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html), e.g.:

```
val x =
    if (true) {
        if ((1..5).any{ it == 4 })
            0
        else
            1
    } else
        2
```

That probably expresses your intent better than a loop would.

You might find it even clearer to re-order the cases, so you can use a [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression):

```
val x = when {
    !true -> 2
    (1..5).any{ it == 4 } -> 0
    else -> 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to solve my problem i used @IR42 first solution, but i had to use it a bit differently:

```
val x = run { 
    if (ok){ 
        for (i in 1..5) 
            if (i == someValue)
                return@run 10
        5
    }
    else 2
}
```